# Meteor Deployment

Tags: javascript, meteor, deployment

Hi there I am trying to deploy my first meteor app (first website too) and I am finding it very hard. 
what I done first I start my Ubuntu server , the ssh onto the server install my app and then run it. But it kept crashing after some time. then I found out too use meteor-up . but I cannot seem to get it working. From all there tutorials its shows a different config file than the one mup init created. But any way I went ahead and done what i think is right.

So this is a example of what i did exactly but with different details. I have no idea if it is correct

```
module.exports = {
    servers: {
        one: {
            host: '1.2.3.4',
            username: 'john'
                // pem:
            password: 'jonhjohn'
                // or leave blank for authenticate from ssh-agent
        }
    },

    meteor: {
        name: 'profit',
        path: '../profit',
        servers: {
            one: {
                host: '1.2.3.4',
                username: 'john'
                    // pem:
                password: 'jonhjohn'
                    // or leave blank for authenticate from ssh-agent
            }
        },
        buildOptions: {
            serverOnly: true,
        },
        env: {
            ROOT_URL: 'http://1.2.3.4:3000/',
            MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://localhost/meteor'
        },

        //dockerImage: 'kadirahq/meteord'
        deployCheckWaitTime: 60
    },

    mongo: {
        oplog: true,
        port: 27017,
        servers: {
            one: {},
        },
    },
};
```

But when I try run mup setup I get

[image]

I have tried everything but I still have no success.Am I even going about this the right way. I read something that said use compose.io but I am a student with not much money. If someone could educated me on this would be great

Comment: You are missing a comma after your username in `meteor.servers.one`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the simple answer is your json was not well formatted. Try this... IT MAY NOT WORK, because of config issues, but it should at least run the json.

```
module.exports = {
   "servers":{
      "one":{
         "host":"1.2.3.4",
         "username":"john",
         "password":"jonhjohn"
      }
   },
   "meteor":{
      "name":"profit",
      "path":"../profit",
      "servers":{
         "one":{
            "host":"1.2.3.4",
            "username":"john",
            "password":"jonhjohn"
         }
      },
      "buildOptions":{
         "serverOnly":true
      },
      "env":{
         "ROOT_URL":"http://1.2.3.4:3000/",
         "MONGO_URL":"mongodb://localhost/meteor"
      },
      "deployCheckWaitTime":60
   },
   "mongo":{
      "oplog":true,
      "port":27017,
      "servers":{
         "one":{

         }
      }
   }
};
```

My strong suggestion is to make sure your json is well formatted by running it through a validator. I use https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ myself, and have no affiliation to this site. Google json validator, there are lots.